# how to use if else in radio button at 2 function

Tags: python, button, tkinter, radio-button

i have the following script. in self.dis (rad.button 3) i want to multiply *10 if active and *100 if not active

```
import tkinter.messagebox
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class Resistor:

def set_band1(self, value):
    self.var_band1.set(value)
    self.update_labels()


def update_labels(self):
    self.dis = 0
    if self.dis != 0:
        v1 = self.var_band1.get()*10
    else:
        v1 = self.var_band1.get()*100

def __init__(self, root):
options = {'font': 'bold', 'bg': 'dimgrey'}

    self.dis  = tk.Radiobutton(resistor_frame, text="3 Band", value=0, command=self.enable_band3, **options)
    self.dis.grid(column=1, row=0

    self.en   = tk.Radiobutton(resistor_frame, text="4 Band", value=1, command=self.disable_band3, **options)
    self.en.grid(column=4, row=0)
```

Comment: You're immediately setting `self.dis` to zero before the `if` statement. Why are you doing that?

Comment: cz i want to choose a condition by value from radio button  i think the value of self.dis is zero so if the value not zero it will be multiply *10 and so does the reverse

Comment: If you set it to zero, `if self.dis != 0` will never be true.

Comment: yap its same if self.dis == 0 will be true. but the "else" condition doesnt work.

Comment: Why do you think it doesn't work? `v1` is a local variable, have you tried adding a print statement to verify it has been set properly? What is `v1` suppose to represent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Radiobuttons require an associated tkinter variable to work properly. You need to create this variable, and then you can use this variable in your conditional statement.

```
def __init__(self, root):
    ...
    self.disvar = tk.IntVar(value=0)
    self.dis  = tk.Radiobutton(..., variable=self.disvar, ...)
    self.en   = tk.Radiobutton(..., variable=self.disvar, ...)
    ...

def update_labels(self):
    if self.disvar.get() != 0:
        v1 = self.var_band1.get()*10
    else:
        v1 = self.var_band1.get()*100
```

You also seem to have the problem that you're setting `v1`, but `v1` is a local variable. You probably need to either set a global variable or an attribute of the class. Just setting a local variable and then returning does nothing since the local variable is destroyed when the function returns.

Answer (score 0):

```
 def update_labels(self):
    if self.disvar.get() != 0:
        v1 = self.var_band1.get()*100
    else:
        v1 = self.var_band1.get()*10

def __init__(self, root):

    self.disvar = tk.IntVar(value=0)
    self.dis  = tk.Radiobutton(resistor_frame, variable=self.disvar, text="3 Band", value=0, command=self.enable_band3, **options)
    self.dis.grid(column=1, row=0)
```